# High-resolution Stack Overflow resources

Tags: discussion, images

The Stack Overflow shop is gone, but I want my Stack Overflow T-Shirt.

Can we get some high-resolution images of some typical Stack Overflow GUI elements and icons to make that stuff ourselves?

Comment: I too wanted the t-shirt, but there was no india country selection in country drop down

Comment: Be careful that you stay with the [Guidelines for the Use of the Stack Exchange Trademarks](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance).

Comment: @jadarnel27 Does that mean we can't make a t-shirt for personal use?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209744/172011

Answer (score 8):

Here is an official source for the logos of the site - although I'm not sure if they are good enough to send for printing...

https://stackexchange.com/about/logos

<sub>Thanks to [Lucifer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141646/hi-res-stackoverflow-resources#comment401030_141647) for that link!</sub>

Comment: you can also get those logos from here http://stackexchange.com/about/logos

Comment: please add above my link into your answer.

Comment: @luc - done! Thanks...