# Can I use Stack Exchange logos on a t-shirt or other apparel?

Tags: discussion, logo, shop, trademark

I happened to notice while on the Super User site that one user's picture shows him wearing a shirt with the Super User logo on it. Interested, I wanted to find out where he got it from. Looking through old questions on Meta, I found out that there used to be a shop.stackexchange.com site that sold Stack Exchange gear. Unfortunately, they no longer sell any merchandise.

Is there any site where I can purchase a Stack Exchange site shirt/hat/etc.? If not, could I create a shirt/hat/etc. myself with one of the sites' logos on it? If so, where can I locate the logos in their largest size?

Comment: You win it, as swag, in contests like [this one](http://www.win8challenge.com/). Related: [What are the rules on using the Stack Overflow logo?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22117/what-are-the-rules-on-using-the-stack-overflow-logo) and [Where can I find image files of Stack Exchange sites' logos?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117766/where-can-i-find-image-files-of-stack-exchange-sites-logos)

Comment: I did notice that it can be won.  I am willing to pay for it though.  Also, the shirt I saw the user wearing had the text 'Super User' along with the logo, which I like better.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure where you're going with this. You start of by saying that you know the store is closed, but then you ask if there's a store. I guess what you're really asking for is an Ebay listing? I suppose I could put mine up for sale... but I'd demand a __ridiculously__ high price.

Comment: The store closed.  But that is not to say that another store hasn't been created to sell Stack Exchange merchandise?  Also, if I were to put it on a shirt myself, I am not using the logo in conjunction with anything else.  It would simply be on a shirt/hat/etc by itself.  I wouldn't be misrepresenting it.  Actually I would be kind of advertising for them.  Anybody seeing the shirt may check it out online and find out what it truly is.  Again, I wouldn't be misrepresenting the brand or gaining money from it or etc.  Is this ok?

Comment: Oh, I wouldn't want your shirt, it is used.  I would want a new one. :)

Comment: You're just assuming it's used. I've never put it on, or even washed it. It's for display only.

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/about/logos

Comment: From @juergend's link I guess that *"Do not use the names or logos owned by Stack Exchange Inc. on any apparel or merchandise without our permission."* covers it...

Comment: They also sometimes spam your mailbox with this stuff for free when you have too much reputation on the particular site.

Comment: @Bart, I would say so, that is why I upvoted his comment.

Comment: @Bart d'oh, that's clear. In my defense, how was I to know that the answer would be found in a document entitled "Guidelines for the Use of the Stack Exchange Trademarks"?

Comment: @PopularDemand Don't worry about it. It's just the kind of "thinking outside the box" that I do from time to time. (On a fun note: you can [get away with a significant amount of logo infringement](http://www.mike-wong.ch/) apparently. Though I would not recommend it ;) )

Comment: @Bart hm... it took me a while to see what you were referring to. I saw that as the outline of a plate that the text was sitting on, not the Nike logo. I guess that means it's different enough?

Comment: @PopularDemand there's also the upside-down McD.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hi-Res Stackoverflow resources](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141646/hi-res-stackoverflow-resources)

Comment: @pop Both Nike and McDonalds (upside down yellow M) sued them. They (Mike Wong) won both cases afaik. Fun fact: they are located next to a McDonalds in Geneva.

Comment: The McDonald's thing is a stretch. I would have never seen that if you guys hadn't explicitly pointed it out. The W in the Wong logo has serifs, and the "arches" change thickness in a completely different way than the McDonald's arches do. I actually find the k more McDonald's-y than the W.

Comment: _Super User site that one user's picture shows him wearing a shirt with the Super User logo on it_ oh, hello ;D

Comment: @Sathya, yup you would be that user.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just to summarize stuff from the comments for the sake of an official answer...

There is no place right now where you can buy Stack Exchange merchandise. Running a swag store  proved to be too complicated, so [we had to close it down](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137579/what-happened-to-the-stack-exchange-store/137580#137580).

We still offer swag to the top users on a site when a site graduates, provide it for various contests and events, and occasionally send it out as gifts, so your best bet for getting some is to be active on your favourite SE sites.

Far as making your own swag goes, our [trademark guidelines](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) cover the use of our [logos](https://stackexchange.com/about/logos) for that purpose:

> **Do not** use the names or logos owned by Stack Exchange Inc. on any apparel or merchandise without our permission.

Comment: What defines a top user? Are top users those who have over 10K when a site graduates?

Comment: @JohnBensin Usually it's the [top two pages of users](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all) some time after the site graduates. We don't start thinking about designing the swag until the top two pages are all users with at least 1000 reputation. The idea behind this "top user swag package" is to reward folks to contribute a lot to the early stages of the site, before it was a sure thing. We'd love to reward more people more regularly, but unfortunately we can't keep offering it because it gets too hard to manage.

Comment: @JohnBensin We still offer site-specific swag for contests, conferences, conventions, etc. as much as we can.

Comment: Thanks for the quick update. I'm certainly not pushing for more or less rewards. The site I'm most active on is set to graduate soon, so when someone mentioned it, my curiosity was piqued.

Comment: I understand why Stack Exchange would want to protect their logo/image.  However, the policy of not providing merch AND not giving us an option to use the logo under any provision (other than jumping through hoops by contacting someone at Stack Exchange) means that we cannot promote you or show any pride in our involvement.  Even Microsoft allows their logo to be used as long as it follows their guidelines (and this is published).  JMHO